# New to Jekyll, after pushing to terminal it fails during build with the error. Process completed with exit code 1

Tags: html, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to make a simple blog and I've followed this guide specifically to help me learn to make a Github pages with Jekyll https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8iOU1ci19Q

Followed the guide as is and when doing a local preview everything works as it should, but when I go to build it, it fails almost instantly. It shows this error. Specifically it stops at the "Test Site" portion of the build.

```
build
Process completed with exit code 1.
```

When looking at the terminal, I get no errors with the building (I don't think)

```
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 407 bytes | 407.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
```

But when looking into code to see the issue, I get this. (Long list off errors)

```
Run bundle exec htmlproofer _site \
Running 3 checks (Scripts, Links, Images) in ["_site"] on *.html files...


Checking 17 internal links
Checking internal link hashes in 1 file
Ran on 11 files!


For the Links > Internal check, the following failures were found:

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/site.webmanifest, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/css/jekyll-theme-chirpy.css, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /categories/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /archives/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /about/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /feed.xml, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /posts/newPost/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/site.webmanifest, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/css/jekyll-theme-chirpy.css, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /categories/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /archives/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /about/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /feed.xml, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /posts/newPost/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/site.webmanifest, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/css/jekyll-theme-chirpy.css, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /categories/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /archives/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /about/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /feed.xml, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /posts/newPost/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /posts/newPost/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/site.webmanifest, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/css/jekyll-theme-chirpy.css, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /categories/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /archives/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /about/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /feed.xml, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /posts/newPost/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/site.webmanifest, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/css/jekyll-theme-chirpy.css, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /categories/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /archives/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /about/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /feed.xml, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /posts/newPost/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /posts/newPost/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/site.webmanifest, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/css/jekyll-theme-chirpy.css, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /categories/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /archives/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /about/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /feed.xml, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /posts/newPost/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /pictures/jigen.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/site.webmanifest, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /assets/css/jekyll-theme-chirpy.css, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /posts/newPost/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/randomthoughts/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /posts/newPost/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/randomthoughts/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/randomthoughts/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags/randomthoughts/, which does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/randomthoughts/index.html:1:

  internally linking to /tags, which does not exist

For the Scripts check, the following failures were found:

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internal script reference /assets/js/dist/page.min.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/404.html:1:

  internal script reference /app.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /assets/js/dist/page.min.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/about/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /app.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /assets/js/dist/misc.min.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/archives/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /app.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /assets/js/dist/categories.min.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/categories/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /app.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /assets/js/dist/home.min.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /app.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /assets/js/dist/post.min.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/posts/newPost/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /app.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /assets/js/dist/commons.min.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /app.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/randomthoughts/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /assets/js/dist/misc.min.js does not exist

* At _site/RadiantHero6/tags/randomthoughts/index.html:1:

  internal script reference /app.js does not exist


HTML-Proofer found 166 failures!
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

It seems like it's missing a lot of files, that do exist but when it's pushing it to main, it doesn't find it.

Currently on a Linux build if that helps.

Tried some STFW but got fixes that didn't seem too helpful, maybe my problem is super simple/user error. Some solutions were to check the _config.yml to see any typos, but I don't see any afaik. When building it finds the link just fine to main branch. I tried to do the workflow through github directly with the same error.

Comment: Solution was checking the dirs, making sure the names were correct with what it's expecting. Mostly with making sure the file was named properly once making the repo.